# HBase master fail to start - impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have configured HBase on top of HDFS for distributed mode.I formatted Hadoop namenode, HDFS is configured correctly. It is up and running.

HBase master is not starting. The error is "impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists". The following is detailed error log for HBase master

```
apreduce/*:/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:CLASS_PATH=.
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine:   env:SSH_CONNECTION=193.60.151.202 36343 192.168.0.84 22
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=/home/ubuntu/hadoop/lib/native
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS=
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_HOME=/home/ubuntu/hbase-0.98.20-hadoop1/bin/..
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HOME=/home/ubuntu
2016-07-13 14:06:19,374 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4
2016-07-13 14:06:19,377 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: vmName=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, vmVendor=Oracle Corporation, vmVersion=25.91-b14
2016-07-13 14:06:19,377 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine:     vmInputArguments=[-Dproc_master, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -Xmx1000m, -   XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -Dhbase.log.dir=/home/ubuntu/hbase-0.98.20-  hadoop1/bin/../logs, -Dhbase.log.file=hbase-ubuntu-master-master.log, -  Dhbase.home.dir=/home/ubuntu/hbase-0.98.20-hadoop1/bin/.., - Dhbase.id.str=ubuntu, -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,RFA, - Djava.library.path=/home/ubuntu/hadoop/lib, -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,RFAS]
2016-07-13 14:06:19,435 DEBUG [main] master.HMaster: master/master/192.168.0.84:60000 HConnection server-to-server retries=350
2016-07-13 14:06:19,649 INFO  [main] ipc.RpcServer: master/master/192.168.0.84:60000: started 10 reader(s).
2016-07-13 14:06:19,722 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2-hbase.properties
2016-07-13 14:06:19,801 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2016-07-13 14:06:19,803 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-07-13 14:06:19,803 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: HBase metrics system started
2016-07-13 14:06:19,807 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2016-07-13 14:06:19,810 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source IPC,sub=IPC registered.
2016-07-13 14:06:19,988 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2016-07-13 14:06:19,988 WARN  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2016-07-13 14:06:20,188 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:135)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3133)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:852)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:790)
Wed Jul 13 15:57:58 UTC 2016 Stopping hbase (via master)
Wed Jul 13 16:06:47 UTC 2016 Stopping hbase (via master)
Wed Jul 13 16:11:11 UTC 2016 Starting master on master
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 125284
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
```

Any pointer to resolve the error is much appreciated....

Comment: Add the version info of hdfs and hbase to your post ?

Comment: Hadoop 2.6.4 and HBase 0.98.20.

Comment: Would you please paste the content of 'hadoop-metrics2-hbase.properties' to the post ?